# Ordenação alfabética em Array com objetos em array PHP

Tags: php, array, classificação

Tenho o seguinte array em php:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array([id] => 1 [nome] => b parceiro um [status] => true [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>)
  [1] => Array([id] => 3 [nome] => f parceiro tres [status] => true [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>)
  [2] => Array([id] => 4 [nome] => z parceiro quatro [status] => false [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>)
  [3] => Array([id] => 5 [nome] => a parceiro cinco [status] => true [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>)
  [4] => Array([id] => 7 [nome] => e parceiro sete [status] => true [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>)
}
```

E tenho um for que posteriormente, irá montar em HTML uma listagem deste array, porém quero fazer esta listagem por ordem alfabética levando em consideração o campo `nome`.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isto? Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dada a entrada:

```
$values = [
  0 => ['id' => 1, 'nome' => "b parceiro um", 'status' => true, 'descricao' => "<p>Descrição do parceiro</p>"],
  1 => ['id' => 3, 'nome' => "f parceiro tres", 'status' => true, 'descricao' => "<p>Descrição do parceiro</p>"],
  2 => ['id' => 4, 'nome' => "z parceiro quatro", 'status'=> false, 'descricao' => "<p>Descrição do parceiro</p>"],
  3 => ['id' => 5, 'nome' => "a parceiro cinco", 'status' => true, 'descricao' => "<p>Descrição do parceiro</p>"],
  4 => ['id' => 7, 'nome' => "e parceiro sete", 'status' => true, 'descricao' => "<p>Descrição do parceiro</p>"],
];
```

Acredito que você consiga resolver seu problema facilmente com a função [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php):

```
usort($values, function($a, $b){ return $a['nome'] >= $b['nome']; });
```

A saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [nome] => a parceiro cinco
            [status] => 1
            [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] => b parceiro um
            [status] => 1
            [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [nome] => e parceiro sete
            [status] => 1
            [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [nome] => f parceiro tres
            [status] => 1
            [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [nome] => z parceiro quatro
            [status] => 
            [descricao] => <p>Descrição do parceiro</p>
        )

)
```

Pode ver o código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HEKg/0) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/GJuxB5).

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema! :D