# Sobre array foreach while loop for...pra deixar resultados na ordem alfabética

Tags: php, foreach, while

```
<?
$n = 0;
$limite = 10;
while ($n <= $limite-1){
$dates = array($user["members"][$n]["rank"]);
foreach ($dates as $value){

echo $value; 

}
$n++;
}
?>
```

ele retorna o seguinte valor:   87 41 34 32 88 26 16 26 48 0

porem eu gostaria de algum método ou forma que eles se apresentassem na ordem crescente...

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo

Comment: Já tentou o [**sort**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php) ?

Comment: [Ordenar valores array php!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260188), [ordenar array multidimensional php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125607), [Ordem alfabética no While?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234030/), [Como organizar itens de um array em ordem alfabetica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/270851), [Como ordenar um array com php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188468), [Ordenação alfabética em Array com objetos em array PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197388).

Comment: Link legal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mostrar os valores e diferenças de arsort(); krsort(); ksort(); sort(); e etc em echos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/como-mostrar-os-valores-e-diferen%c3%a7as-de-arsort-krsort-ksort-sort-e-e)